# Text file creation with non subscriptable objects

Tags: python

I want to create a text file with NON subscriptable objects in Python and I do not know how to proceed. I want to extract each month of the list and create a separate row for each. Here is how the list of non subscriptable objects and the error look like:

[image]

The code that I use is the following:

```
months=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'Novemeber', 'December']

for i in range(len(sections)): 

    if (' tax ' in sections[i]
    or ' Tax ' in sections[i]
    or ' policy ' in sections[i]
    or ' Policy ' in sections[i]):

        pat=re.compile("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(m) for m in months]), re.M)
        month = pat.search("\n".join(sections[i].splitlines()[0:6]))
        print(month)

outfile = open('H:/Uncertainty_Data/A_2005_Months.txt', 'w')
outfile.writelines(month['match'])
outfile.close
```

Any help much appreciate it!

Cheers,

Comment: It seems that you are writing the matched object to your file instead of the matched string. Can you update your question with providing the regex and `month` dictionary.

Comment: Hey, I have just uploaded them

Comment: What is `month['match']` meant to be doing? What makes you think that it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`month` is a regex match object, and if you want to access the text matched by it, you can't index into it (it's not an iterable).

You want to use

```
outfile.write(month.group(0))
```

although (since you're doing this outside of the loop) that will only write the last month that was matched. If you want to collect all the matches and write them to a file, do something like

```
outputs = []
pat = re.compile("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(m) for m in months]), re.M)

for section in sections: 
    if any(item in section for item in (' tax ', ' Tax ', ' policy ', ' Policy ')):
        month = pat.search("\n".join(section.splitlines()[0:6]))
        outputs.append(month.group(0))

with open('H:/Uncertainty_Data/A_2005_Months.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(outputs)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer which contains a really good explanation of the problem as well. Any ideas how to manage to write all months instead of only the last one?

Comment: Edited my answer and made your code a bit more pythonic along the way - always iterate over a sequence directly instead of using a C-style index variable `i` and `range(len(foo))` etc.; also use `with` blocks to ensure that files are closed. Your line `outfile.close` didn't do anything (it would have if you'd written `outfile.close()`) but in the case of an error occuring (as in your example), the file would have been left open - not so if you use a `with` block...

Comment: thanks very much for the answer, the code looks fantastic. Nevertheless, I am getting the following error: in outputs.append(month.group(0)) : object has no attribute 'group'. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Hm, that could happen if there is no match - if `re.search()` returns `None`, then `None.group(0)` won't work. Although I would have expected the error message to read `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`...so you need to decide if not having a match *should* be an error or if you want to ignore it. Just wrap the `outputs.append()` line in a `try:/except AttributeError:` block and either print an error message or  `pass` in the  `except` clause of that block.

Comment: that is how the error reads: 'NonType' object has no attribute 'group'.